# WebStorm and nodejs with live-reload

Tags: node.js, livereload

I have the latest nodejs server installed with the `yalr` module on the backend.

On the frontend I use the WebStorm IDE which auto-saves changes. This forces a refresh in my browser. After the refresh the changes are not shown! I still see the old version!

How could I configure yalr to refresh with the newly changed source files?
I've tried setting the `debounce` parameter, however it seem to do nothing no matter what I set it. The `sleepAfter` parameter didn't help either.
I should note that sometimes the page refreshes twice which, while annoying, DOES actually load the changes. But I can't depend on that.

How did you set up live-reload for the frontend?

Comment: for me i use yeoman :)

Comment: I'm using sailsjs, so yeoman seems unnecessary. But yeah, I had success with yeoman in the past and tried to used the same configuration with my current project, but I semi-failed. At least the server auto-reload works! :)